# Is there a way to make executionTimeout take effect while debugging?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, timeout

I would like to debug a website, but also cause the [`httpRuntime executionTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) setting to take effect. However, the documentation says:

> This time-out applies only if the
>   debug attribute in the compilation
>   element is False.

Is there any way to enable `executionTimeout` when `debug="True"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After more than a week of searching and trying various hacks, I'm confident in saying that, as of now, there is no reasonable way to have the `httpRuntime executionTimeout` setting take effect while the `compilation debug` flag is set to true.

One possible terrible hack workaround is to somehow trick the system into thinking that more than 30,000,000 seconds (just over 347 days) have elapsed, which is what `executionTimeout` is overridden to when `debug` is true.

Comment: Thanks for researching this, even though the answer is not what one would hope for.

Answer (score 4):

If you use ASP.NET MVC then [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1715081.aspx/1?web%20config%20executionTimeout%20not%20working%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC) may help.
ASP.NET MVC (version < 4) doesn't support this timeout.

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting, because I have debugging sessions timeout on me all the time when I'm just sitting there looking at the code.  Is there another timeout value that is handled by IIS rather than ASP.NET?

Comment: The `sessionState timeout` and `forms timeout` values are still in effect while you're debugging - it's likely that if you have `compilation debug="True"` and are getting a timeout that it's from forms or the session.