# asp.net - post file gives 404 page result even though posted file is well under maxRequestLength

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload

I have a page on my ASP.NET site which uploads files.
I have attempted to tweak the web.config file to allow for larger uploads.
In my web.config, I set:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

On my page, when I attempt to upload smaller files, no issue...even at 25MB.
However, when I attempt to upload a 50MB file, I still get a 404 error page.

NOTE: I have a flash control on a different page which can upload almost 2gb with no issues, using this same web.config setting.
Same result on different PCs, same result when posted to different web servers.
My web server is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Any ideas of the cause?  Why would flash be ok, but plain jane upload control have this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer.  Windows Server 2008 R2 is using IIS7 (of course), and in IIS7, you have to set the following in your web.config file (in my example to increase the limit to 2gb):

```
 <system.webserver>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 <system.webserver>
```

This worked, when everything else didn't.  IIS7 by default limits uploads to 30mb unless this override is set.

Comment: Thanks. Experienced exact same issue in an mvc 4 app running on IIS 7.5. Your fix worked.  The only caution would be that could make the server more vulnerable to Dos attacks if it's public.

Answer (score 1):

The executionTimeout applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False. (see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)

So try it when starting your application in Release config.

Comment: So does that mean that it will be ignored if in debug mode?  Meaning, if I raise the number to extend the timeout, the actual timeout will still be the default?

Comment: Yes. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231015/is-there-a-way-to-make-executiontimeout-take-effect-while-debugging)