# Broken connection does not time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

We've got a basic ASP Web API setup: a single `ApiController` with a number of methods configured as end-points for POST requests. These receive rather large JSON streams which are deserialized through the `[FromBody]` attribute.

What happens is that if connections are interrupted/terminated, the requests are kept in the IIS Worker Process Request Queue. They don't seem to time out. Worse, as *something* in the `RequestHandler` is keeping busy, after a number of failures and "stuck" requests, the CPU consumption is near 100%. Logging indicated that the action methods in the `ApiController` haven't executed as yet.

To make a large story short. Is there anything which I can do to let these methods time-out so they will be removed from the queue? Normal web.config doesn't seem to work.

Comment: set debug = false if its true..
Find a related discussion here
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231015/is-there-a-way-to-make-executiontimeout-take-effect-while-debugging)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

in most cases compilation debug = true is the problem..
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490017/asp-net-httpruntime-executiontimeout-not-working-and-yes-debug-false) is some more discussion on similar issue..
if this also doesn't help... take a memory dump of w3wp process when CPU consumption is near 100% and do a dump analysis using windows debugging tools..

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Recycling settings of your application pool. In this settings from IIS you can recycle the application pool using a schedule, request number or a specific MB limit.